# With Aegean airlines GoLight how many pieces of cabin baggage? Are seats allocated together?

Tags: hand-luggage, seating, aegean-airlines

In Aegean [golight](http://en.aegeanair.com/travel-information/fares-classes/economy-class/) if I buy 4 tickets (in golight) how many items of hand baggage can I bring with me?

And again if I buy 4 tickets (we are family 2 + 2) is there any way for me to be sure we are going to be sitting together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Aegean website says that [golight passengers are allowed one free piece of cabin luggage each](http://en.aegeanair.com/travel-information/baggage/cabin-baggage/):

[image: golight cabin baggage]

The only moment in which you can select your seats is upon checking in. Fortunately [Aegean allows its GoLight passengers to checkin online up to 48h before departure.](http://en.aegeanair.com/travel-information/fares-classes/economy-class/) Note however that the airline has the right to move you to a different seat if they want to, so guaranteeing that you'll be sitting together is kind of impossible. It's likely though that your selected seats won't be changed unless there's a real need for it.

Comment: just to be clear so its supposed to be 1 cabin baggage per golight ticket right?

Comment: @Jas yes exactly.